# Read a table from an ESRI file geodatabase (.gdb) using R

Tags: r, file-geodatabase, table, rgdal

I am trying to read a table directly from an ESRI file geodatabase into R.  An example data file can be downloaded [here](https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2014/01/Zone9_2014_01.zip).  The database contains a point feature class (Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast) and two linked tables (Zone9_2014_01_Vessel and Zone9_2014_01_Voyage).  You can read the shapefile in R using `readOGR` from the `rgeos` package:

```
library(rgeos)
library(downloader)

download("https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2014/01/Zone9_2014_01.zip", dest="Zone9_2014_01.zip", mode="wb")
unzip("Zone9_2014_01.zip", exdir = ".")

#  Not Run (loads large point file)
#  broadcast <- readOGR(dsn = "Zone9_2014_01.gdb", layer = "Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast")
```

The two linked tables also show when you use `ogrListLayers` or `ogrInfo`.  However, `ogrInfo` gives a warning:

> Warning message:
>   In ogrInfo("Zone9_2014_01.gdb", layer =  "Zone9_2014_01_Vessel") :
>     ogrInfo: all features NULL

And if you try to use `readOGR` on the tables you get an error:

```
vessel <- readOGR(dsn = "Zone9_2014_01.gdb", layer = "Zone9_2014_01_Vessel")
```

> Error in readOGR(dsn = "Zone9_2014_01.gdb", layer =  "Zone9_2014_01_Vessel") : 
>     no features found
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  :
>     ogrInfo: all features NULL

Thus, it appears that only geographical features can be read by readOGR.  Is there any way to import the tables directly into R or is the only solution to first export them from ArcGIS as *.dbf (or *.txt) files as in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/49848/35320) answer?

As an addition, if anyone can provide calls from R to a python script that automates the export of *csv (preferrably) or *.dbf files, that would be an acceptable work-around.  The solution just needs to be scalable and automated.

Comment: Have you seen the new integration of R and ArcGIS? https://r-arcgis.github.io/ maybe something useful for your work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...I had seen mention of it at one point, but never looked into it more thoroughly.  Perhaps now would be a good time to do that!

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov, if you want to write up a short answer for this solution, I will accept it since it is what I was looking for.

Comment: It looks like the R-ArcGIS bridge that @AlexTereshenkov mentioned does have the functionality to read tables directly into R. The integration requires ArcGIS Desktop >10.3.1 (or ArcGIS Pro) and R >3.2. 64-bit R can only be used with the 64-bit background geoprocessing (and only allows use from ArcGIS, not from R) or ArcGIS Pro. Once the bindings are installed, you can use the package `arcgisbbinding` in R. The function `arc.open()` will open the table as an `arc.dataset-class object`. To open directly as a `data.table`, use function `arc.select`.

Comment: good to know. I've added an answer just to close the thread, but you have figured everything out on your own, so accept but don't upvote :D

Comment: Cotton.Rockwood, Did you finally find a direct solution to read a very large table from gdb in R? I have exactly the same problem, but as my attribute tables contain about 300,000,000 rows, converting them first to shapefile as suggested above takes too long. Any light will be more than welcome!

Comment: @Pasciflora do you have access to ArcGIS Desktop >10.3.1?  If so, using the 'arcgisbinding' package as mentioned above and in Alex's answer.  That is the solution that I ended up using.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This can now be read by `sf`, with

```
vessel <- sf::st_read(dsn = "Zone9_2014_01.gdb", layer = "Zone9_2014_01_Vessel")
```

It returns a warning (no feature geometries present) but also a data.frame with the table. See the thread that started here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2018-February/026344.html

Comment: strange, I wasn't able to run this on 3 machines: I get an error, not a warning?

Comment: you'll need to install the dev version from github, from source, or wait until 0.6-1 release next month

Comment: dont forget st_layers( "Zone9_2014_01.gdb")  as a quick lookup method for layer names

Answer (score 9):

I use GDAL 2.0.2 that is "shipped" with FDGB support and without a [third party a FGDB driver](http://ww.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html) to investigate that stuff. The test environment is Debian Jessie 64-bit.

In short, it seems, that the "layer" `Zone9_2014_01_Vessel` contains pure attribute data and the layer `Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast` contains position data. You can use a workaround within R via a system call and the conversation of the GDB to a shapefile container (last script at the end of the answer).

Here are the investigation steps:

```bash
$ mkdir ~/dev.d/gis-se.d/gdb 
$ cd ~/dev.d/gis-se.d/gdb
$ wget https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2014/01/Zone9_2014_01.zip
$ unzip Zone9_2014_01.zip
$ ogrinfo Zone9_2014_01.gdb Zone9_2014_01_Vessel | head -20
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `Zone9_2014_01.gdb'
      using driver `OpenFileGDB' successful.

Layer name: Zone9_2014_01_Vessel
Geometry: None <---------------------------- HERE 
Feature Count: 1282
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
FID Column = OID
MMSI: Integer (0.0)
IMO: Integer (0.0)
CallSign: String (255.0)
Name: String (255.0)
VesselType: Integer (0.0)
Length: Integer (0.0)
Width: Integer (0.0)
DimensionComponents: String (255.0)
OGRFeature(Zone9_2014_01_Vessel):1
  MMSI (Integer) = 367603345
```

As you see the field `Geometry` is set to `None`.  You can convert the data to a shape file using `ogr2ogr` and get also only a dbase attribute file:

```bash
$ ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI SHAPEFILE' test Zone9_2014_01.gdb Zone9_2014_01_Vessel
$ ls test

Zone9_2014_01_Vessel.dbf
```

Geometries (positions) can be found in the layer `Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast`.

```
$ ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI SHAPEFILE' test Zone9_2014_01.gdb
$ ls test

Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast.dbf  
Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast.shp  
Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast.prj  
Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast.shx  
Zone9_2014_01_Vessel.dbf
Zone9_2014_01_Voyage.dbf
```

Vessel and Voyage containing no position data according to the [AIS messages protocol](http://catb.org/gpsd/AIVDM.html).

Here the complete workaround in R using a system call for the GDB to shapefile conversation and the package `foreign` to read the dbf's:

```
# Load module to get readOGR
require('rgdal');

# Load module to get read.dbf
require('foreign');

# goto the directory with the GDB stuff
setwd('~/dev.d/gis-se.d/gdb')

# Conversation to a shapefile container 
system("ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI SHAPEFILE' test Zone9_2014_01.gdb") 

# read the vessels
vessel <- read.dbf('test/Zone9_2014_01_Vessel.dbf');

# read hte voyage data
voyage <- read.dbf('test/Zone9_2014_01_Voyage.dbf');

# read the geometries in broad cast
broadcast <- readOGR('test/Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast.shp','Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast')

OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile
Source: "test/Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast.shp", layer: "Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast"
with 1639274 features
It has 10 fields

# is vessel OK?    
head(vessel)

MMSI IMO CallSign Name VesselType Length Width   DimensionC
1 367603345  NA     <NA> <NA>         50     20     6     7,13,3,3
2 563000574  NA     <NA> <NA>         70    276    40 188,88,20,20
3 367449580  NA     <NA> <NA>         31     28    10     9,19,5,5
4 367302503  NA     <NA> <NA>         31     20     8     8,12,4,4
5 304003909  NA     <NA> <NA>         71    222    32 174,48,21,11
6 210080027  NA     <NA> <NA>         71    294    32 222,72,22,10

# is voyage OK?
head(voyage)

VoyageID           Destinatio Cargo Draught        ETA  StartTime    EndTime      MMSI
1       12                 KAKE    50      20       <NA> 2014-01-01       <NA> 367603345
2       23             YOKOHAMA    70     125 2014-01-11 2014-01-01 2014-01-30 563000574
3       38         KETCHIKAN AK    31      40 2014-11-12 2014-01-01       <NA> 367449580
4       52 CLARENCE STRAIT LOGS    31      30 2014-09-12 2014-01-01       <NA> 367302503
5       62               JP TYO    71      90 2014-01-13 2014-01-01 2014-01-31 304003909
6       47           VOSTOCHNYY    71     106 2014-01-13 2014-01-01       <NA> 210080027
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a recently released integration between the R and ArcGIS from Esri, called [R ArcGIS Tools](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge-install). It provides integration between R and ArcGIS making it possible to interchangeably access R tools and ArcGIS resources. You should be able to access geodatabase feature classes/tables with this integration.

Sample R tools are available [here](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge/tree/master/package/arc/inst/examples) and sample tools illustrating R usage in geoprocessing scripts are [here](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-sample-tools).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you can do this with readOGR but try

```
vessel <- readOGR(dsn = "Zone9_2014_01.gdb", layer = "Zone9_2014_01_Vessel", dropNULLGeometries = FALSE)
```

If that doesn't work try `ogr2ogr` directly, which can export non-geometries to table. (Maybe try R package `gdalUtils` to run that, once you've got your process down.)

Comment: Unfortunately, `readOGR` does not have the capability to read gdb tables.

Comment: It probably does, now.

Comment: Still not as of rgdal 1.2-8, gdal 2.0.1

Comment: It's called OpenFileGDB in ogrDrivers()$name, perhaps you are trying to read a raster? That's still being implemented, either way if you want to find out you could post a question with details about your system and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

This custom function basically follows the path outlined by @huckfinn but uses the `gdalUtils` library suggested by @mdsumner.

```
read_GDB_Layer <- function(dsn, layerName, overwrite = T) {
   conversionDir <- tempdir()

   gdalUtils::ogr2ogr(src_datasource_name = dsn, 
                      dst_datasource_name = conversionDir, 
                      f = "ESRI Shapefile", layer = layerName, 
                      verbose = T, overwrite = overwrite)

   df <- foreign::read.dbf(file.path(conversionDir, paste0(layerName, ".dbf")))

   return(df)
}
```

Run it like this:

```
vsl <- read_GDB_Layer(dsn = "Zone9_2014_01.gdb", layerName = "Zone9_2014_01_Vessel")
vyg <- read_GDB_Layer(dsn = "Zone9_2014_01.gdb", layerName = "Zone9_2014_01_Voyage")
```

If you don't already have `gdal` installed, you will need to install it to provide access to `gdalUtils`.  You can find binaries and instructions for 'gdal' installation [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install GDAL through Conda and run readOGR with the following steps.

Programs needed:
Rstudio (download available here: https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/)
Anaconda3 (download available here: https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual)

You will need to install GDAL in order to run the Rstudio functions to open the .gdb files. One way to install GDAL is through Conda, which I will describe here:

Installing GDAL in Conda:

1. Install Anaconda3 at the linked provided up.
2. Search for Anaconda Navigator in windows search box.
3. Click on Environments on the left hand side of the Anaconda Navigator.
4. Create a new Environment with the + buttom on the bottom left.
5. On the top bar of the environment, click on the drop bown and select "not installed".
6. Search for gdal in the "not installed" packages.
7. Install r-gdalutils, r-rgdal, gdal, and libgdal. (I'm not sure if all of these are actually necessary, I just installed anything with the name gdal). The installation can take a few minutes.

The readGDBlayer function worked for the 2014 .gdb files on Marine Cadastre (where the sample data originated), but was unable to open .gdb files on 2009 - 2013. I am not sure why this is. The readOGR function was able to open the .gdb files from 2009 - 2013

Here is a link to the 2009 AIS data that you can download https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2009/index.html . Does anyone know why readGDBlayer function will not work with this data?

Comment: Please do not ask questions in Answers.