# How to read a feature class in an Esri Personal GeoDatabase using R?

Tags: r, personal-geodatabase, rgdal, r-bridge

I have feature classes in a personal geodatabase on a Win 8.1 machine (r 3.4.2, rgdal 1.2-15) and, as mentioned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/60198/90872), there is a requirement for Access users to also interact with them.

I have adjusted the code sample found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151613/how-to-read-feature-class-in-file-geodatabase-using-r) (which works perfectly for a file geodatabase):

```
require(rgdal)

# The input personal geodatabase
pgdb <- "C:/path/to/your/personalgeodatabase.mdb"

# Confirm the PGeo driver is available
subset(ogrDrivers(), grepl("PGeo", name))
```

Which returns:

```
   name                 long_name write  copy isVector
49 PGeo ESRI Personal GeoDatabase FALSE FALSE     TRUE
```

Then, at this point, ogrListLayers(dsn) fails:

```
# List all feature classes in a personal geodatabase
fc_list <- ogrListLayers(pgdb)
```

> Error in ogrListLayers(pgdb) : Cannot open data source

I have tried adding path.expand:

```
fc_list <- ogrListLayers(path.expand(pgdb))
```

And I have also confirmed that for [gdal](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pgeo.html) (and so rgdal), that

> Personal Geodatabases are accessed by passing the file name of the .mdb file to be accessed as the data source name. On Windows, no ODBC DSN is required.

I successfully accessed the feature classes using [R-ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/184775/90872) but that requires an ArcGIS licence, and so does not really solve the problem.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you use `ogrinfo` on the command line? I see more informative errors from that than from `rgdal::ogrInfo`, but I'm on Linux so I think my problem with a test PGeo is ODBC-related.

Comment: @spacedman thanks for the suggestion, I ran ogrInfo and it worked, then went back and ran orgListLarers and it surprisingly also worked!! (argh!)  I can only suspect installing R-ArcGIS changed something during install as i believe that is the only thing that changed between composing the question and now. I'm pondering requesting that this question be closed...

Comment: Belay that close request option.. I just installed R on another machine (of course now @ r 3.4.2, rgdal 1.2-16), and ran the test code and again ogrListLayers, and ogrInfo, failed - I will not install R-ArcGIS on this other (Win 7) machine for now and have added a tag for r-bridge to this question.

@Spacedman as suggested I ran ogrinfo from the command line and it failed but I suspect this result may send us off topic since I had this odd success with rgdal::ogrInfo (see previous comment)

Comment: Is the file also not open in Access? Can you point to a suitable example file? (I'd try reading as  straight query with RODBC or odbc, then converting the binary list colum with sf tools - or trying with sf directly). I'd also test with GDAL command line tools, that's really the only way to isolate if there's an R problem, but assumes a bit of system installing.

Comment: @mdsumner - file was not also open in Access nor ArcGIS - I'm going with your 32-bit R answer as as the solution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: *this answer is out of date, there is a 64-bit support for Access now, and rgdal is going to be defunct in a year or so.*

You are on Windows so I will assume you are on a 64-bit machine, running 64-bit R by default.

Try using `rgdal::ogrListLayers` from the 32-bit version of R, you can find it in the x86 folder of the /bin/ folder - parallel to the one `x64` one I presume you are running. (Right click on the R shortcut for Properties to find it, or use `R.home` and trace from there. )

I'm sure that's required for this driver, I always have to run this mode of R for RODBC for these files. It's kind of "well-known" in that experts-only way of these things :)

Comment: Bingo - that's what changed when I installed R-ArcGIS, I switched to 32-bit R for full compatibility w/ArcGIS 10.x! thanks much @mdsumner